# cron starts ev. min script, that sleeps some times for 1200s

Tags: bash, cron, sleep

I wrote a script, that sleeps some times for 1200s.
That script must be executed through cron every minute.

If my script pauses 1200s, will cron still start a new process?

If so, how can I set this to forward sleep command to cron so that the script is not executed for the time being.

Thanks for your time and help,
NaLa

Answer (score 0):

Cron will keep starting new versions as configured. It does not care about its children: you might be running the same script but it picks up a different downloaded file every minute, for instance.

You can't tell cron to hold off. There are at least two known ways to work this. Both have disadvantages.

(1) Don't use cron. Have the script call itself through the `at` command, like `echo myScript | at 'now + 1 minute'`

(2) Have your script detect it has a copy already running, and exit before doing anything more. You can use a lock file for this.

In both cases, if your script breaks before it starts the at or releases the lock-file, it will not get to run until you intervene. There are ways to work around this, at the cost of more complexity.